# Is there a way to read text from a particular region in PDF file in C#

Tags: c#, pdf

I'm trying to read a text from particular region in PDF file. The text may or may not spanned across multiple lines.

I've tried `iTextSharp.text.Rectangle` but it works for fixed coordinates. Below is an example of PDF file. Is there any way to read the highlighted text in C#?

[image]

Comment: As far as I know, not possible. you need to analyze the document when it is parsed and find out if there is a reference tag around the text you need to fetch that does not change, and see if you can use it to fetch the content.

Comment: Depends. Pdf != Pdf. In a PDF with Text-Layer, you'd need to find the position and extract. In an Image-Only PDF, you need to perform OCR.

Comment: ^^ and even with text-layer, you still have to find what you want to extract... which can get _very_ complex.

Answer (score 1):

The LEADTOOLS [Document Analyzer](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/tutorials/dotnet-console-parse-data-with-the-document-analyzer.html) can go through text in a PDF (either directly parsed or obtained through OCR) and locate specific words through pattern recognition.

The code for this would be something as follows:

```
// Load the PDF 
LEADDocument document = DocumentFactory.LoadFromFile(inputFile, new LoadDocumentOptions());
// Initialize the Document Analyzer
DocumentAnalyzer analyzer = new DocumentAnalyzer()
{
   Reader = new UnstructuredDataReader(),
   QueryContext = new FileRepositoryContext(ruleSet)
};
DocumentAnalyzerRunOptions options = new DocumentAnalyzerRunOptions { ElementQuery = new RepositoryQuery() };
// Run the analyzer
List<ElementSetResult> results = analyzer.Run(document, options);
```

Where the `ruleSet` is a JSON file containing the search pattern to be sought. In this case, it would look for the `FAA 2022-20-05$` and `FAA 2022\-20\-05 PARA(?=.*[\s\S]\(G\)\(1\))` patterns.

Any matches would be put in a collection of [ElementResult](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/dh/doxa/elementresult.html) objects which you can cycle through and process.

```
foreach (ElementSetResult result in results)
   foreach (ElementResult item in result.Items)
      Console.WriteLine(item.Value);
```

For example, I used the code above to highlight the start of the text you are seeking in a PDF I created based on your screenshot:
[image: Target Regions highlighted]

(Disclaimer: I am an employee of the vendor of this toolkit)